# Scala MD5 equivalent of this PHP line

Tags: scala

This MD5 call has 3 arguments, "MD5", the string, and then the $transaction_key

```
hash_hmac("md5", $api_login_id . "^" . $fp_sequence . "^" . $fp_timestamp . "^" . $amount . "^", $transaction_key);
```

How would I reproduce this in Scala? I can't find an MD5 function that takes a "key".

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609899/java-equivalent-to-phps-hmac-sha1 it's for Java but the library used by Scala is Java's anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a Scala version derived from [this Java answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11102291/334519):

```
def encode(message: String, key: String) = {
  val mac = javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance("HmacMD5")
  mac.init(new javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes, "HmacMD5"))
  mac.doFinal(message.getBytes).map("%02x".format(_)).mkString
}
```

It produces the same output as PHP's `hash_hmac` for me on a couple of quick tests.