# basic encryption for game data

Tags: java, encryption

I think i'm looking for some sort of basic file encryption but don't know where to start.

I'm looking for someone to tell me where to start looking or, even better, offer some code.

I've written a game that currently saves data to a general text file. This of course could be changed by anyone who wished to do so.

What i need is to create a file that can store integers and strings that is difficult if not impossible to be edited outside of the game.

In my searching i came across .dat files but they seemed more complicated that what i'm looking for.

All help is appreciated, Alex.

Comment: Did you search? Both Google and SO provide a wealth of hits. That's where I'd start.

Comment: yes, the things that i've found cover very detailed encryptions and nothing relating to just hiding basic information. i've found nothing relating directly to games and was hoping to hear something from someone with experience.

Comment: That it's game data is irrelevant. There's no difference between "basic information" and "information". The first SO answer in the Google search covered everything from XOR to ROT-13 to actual encryption. You said "difficult if not impossible to be edited outside the game"--how do you think you'll do that without a "very detailed encryption"?

Comment: i guess i was being optimistic, the fact that it was game data was meant to imply that its dosn't need to be extremly secure but can't be changed by average joe either.

Comment: A One Time Pad is the only way I know of how to make it "impossible" (Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad)... but I don't think that would apply here... So you'll really just want to make it really difficult for anyone to modify. Looks like you might have some good responses to select from.

Comment: @AlexMusk Statement still stands--search SO and Google; there are tons of examples, from simple to complex. I'm not sure what you meant by "impossible" other than "really, really difficult". Hell, you could just zip it and change the extension.

Comment: Whatever you do, I can open the JAR file for the game, find the method which is decrypting the XML, and do the same thing, no?

Answer (score 2):

You can write your data to a ByteBuffer and then you can distort your data by a simple algorithm. For example, assume that the data you want to save is a String array, you can do this:

```
String[] data; // the data you want to save
int byteLength = 0;
byte[][] bytes = new byte[data.length][];

// Calculate the length of the content.
for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    bytes[i] = data[i].getBytes();
    byteLength += bytes[i].length;
    byteLength += 4; // this is for an integer, which is for the length of the String
}

// Transfer the content to a ByteBuffer object
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(byteLength);
for(int i=0; i<bytes.length; i++) {
    // Put the length of the current byte array
    buffer.putInt(bytes[i].length);
    for(int j=0; j<bytes[i].length; j++) {
        // Reverse the byte so that it can't be understood
        buffer.put((byte)(~bytes[i][j])); 
    }
}
```

After writing all of your content to the ByteBuffer object, you can take the resulting byte array and write it down to a file.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("YourFileName.anyExtension");
fos.write(buffer.array());
fos.close();
```

While reading the file back, you should first read an integer, which is the length of the data you should read as byte array, then you should read this byte array.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("YourFileName.anyExtension");
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
byte[] bytes;
while(dis.available()) {
    int length = dis.readInt();
    bytes = new byte[length];
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        // Those bytes were reversed, right?
        bytes[i] = (byte)(~dis.readByte());
    }
    // Convert byte array to String
    String str = new String(bytes);
    list.add(str);
}
```

Now you have an ArrayList of your String data.

Of course this is not the best, the safest, and the fastest algorithm. You can always find or create faster. But I think this is a good example of doing those kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java you can just try and create a class that implements Serializable This way you can just create an object with all your meta info stored inside, serialize it, and when you wanna load it just deserialize it again.

Its not very safe though since you only need to know have the class it was made with, to deserialize it. But it is something to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [digital signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature), specifically HMACs. Those are pretty much exactly what you need, and the Java Crypto framework should make things fairly straightforward. Here's a potentially relevant SO entry: [How to generate an HMAC in Java equivalent to a Python example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208160/how-to-generate-an-hmac-in-java-equivalent-to-a-python-example)

Answer (score 0):

You could pass your file writing stream thru a `CipherOutputStream`

Generate a random string, or number or anything. get its byte array, produce a key, and use it to encrypt your file.

```
    byte password[] = (WHAT YOUR WANT. STRING, NUMBER, etc.).getBytes();
    DESKeySpec desKeySpec;
    try {

        desKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(password);
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
        SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(desKeySpec);

        Cipher desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        // Create stream
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Your file here");
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(bos, desCipher);
    }
```

Now you can write to the file using `cos`

Reading the file is done the same way using the `SecretKey` object

```
SecretKey key = loadKey(); // Deserialize your SecretKey object
try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("Your file here");
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(bis, cipher);
```

now you can read using `cis`

The downside is you need to keep the `SecretKey` object (Serialize it or something) it wouldn't be a problem for any low level hacker to get the data (since the key is stored on the device) but it wouldn't allow just changing your data using a text editor.