# How to call an external JavaScript files methods from JMeter

Tags: javascript, jmeter, hmac, sha256, cryptojs

I'm trying to produce a HMAC SHA256 signature for a SOAP/XML-RPC JMeter Request that I am building.
I have found a JavaScript library that should do the trick for me:

http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#HMAC

The issue is that I can't find a way to call the external JavaScript files methods from JMeter.

Any help would really be appreciated with this or a suggestion for an alternative to preform the task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use any external JS libraries to generate HMAC. This functionality [is available in Java SE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3208472/841064). You can use Beanshell Sampler to execute Java code.

If this functionality wouldn't be available in Java SE, you could:

- use [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler)
- use [BSF Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BSF_Sampler), set language to javascript and attach file with script
- put Jar of chosen library to Jmeter's lib folder. Then this library will be loaded by JMeter  at startup time and you can use it through Beanshell sampler

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm new to JMeter and BeanShell and am from a C# background so it may take me some time to implement this through Java/BeanShell. I'll look into your suggestion as an alternative to calling the external JavaScript files methods. Does anybody know if it is possible to call external JavaScript methods from JMeter?

Comment: @Mike as I told it's possible using OS Process Sampler. But it will be better to use Beanshell

Comment: You can also use BSF Sampler, set language to javascript and attach file with script

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction here. Due to time constraints I stuck with the JavaScript solution, which I am more comfortable with. I used the BSF sampler as per your latest comment but still have problems calling the code from external JS file. In the end to get me over the hump, I just pasted the code from the two file I wanted "hmac-sha256.js" and "enc-base64-min.js" into the "Script to run" text area. I then called it like so:

Comment: Opps. Posted before finishing comment: `var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("TextToHash", "Secret");
hash = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
vars.put("hash", hash);` I was then able to reference this variable in my request sampler like so `<a:hash>${hash}</a:hash>`