# Best way of using HMACSHA-384 in Android

Tags: android

Which is the best way to use the `HMACSHA-384` algorithm?

Should I add https://code.google.com/p/dalvik/wiki/JavaxPackages just to use that algorithm or there is a smaller version of it?

Answer (score 0):

`BouncyCastle` (the security provider in Android) should have it.

See [How to generate an HMAC in Java equivalent to a Python example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208160/how-to-generate-an-hmac-in-java-equivalent-to-a-python-example) for example usage (of course, replace `HmacMD5` with your desired algorithm).

Should the built-in `BouncyCastle` prove insufficient, there's a repackaged version called [`SpongyCastle`](https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle/), which definitely has it.