# Clojure (or Java) equivalent to Ruby's HMAC.hexdigest

Tags: github, clojure, hmac, hmacsha1

When setting a webhook with the Github API, I can provide a secret. When Github sends me a POST request, this secret is used [to encode one of the headers](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/#create-a-hook):

> The value of this header is computed as the HMAC hex digest of the body, using the secret as the key.

On the manual page, they link to [this Ruby example](https://github.com/github/github-services/blob/f3bb3dd780feb6318c42b2db064ed6d481b70a1f/lib/service/http_helper.rb#L77)

```
OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(HMAC_DIGEST, secret, body)
```

I need a way to reproduce this line in Clojure.

Googling around, I found a number of example functions ([1](https://crossclj.info/ns/clj-hmac/0.1.0/clj-hmac.core.html),[2](https://crossclj.info/fun/leiningen.jack-in/hex-digest.html),[3](https://crossclj.info/fun/caribou.auth/hexdigest.html)) for this purpose, but none of them worked. I'm clearly doing something wrong, because they all provide the same result, but it doesn't match the header I receive from Github.

For example, this is the simplest implementation I managed to cook up.

```
(ns website.test
  (:import javax.crypto.Mac
           javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec
           org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64))

;;; Used in core.clj to verify that the payload matches the secret.x
(defn- hmac
  "Generates a Base64 HMAC with the supplied key on a string of data."
  [^String data]
  (let [algo "HmacSHA1"
        signing-key (SecretKeySpec. (.getBytes hook-secret) algo)
        mac (doto (Mac/getInstance algo) (.init signing-key))]
    (str "sha1="
         (String. (Base64/encodeBase64 (.doFinal mac (.getBytes data)))
                  "UTF-8"))))
```

Calling it on a particular `body` with a particular `hook-secret` set, gives me `"sha1=VtNhKZDOHPU4COL2FSke2ArvtQE="`. Meanwhile, the header I get from Github is `sha1=56d3612990ce1cf53808e2f615291ed80aefb501`.

Clearly, Github is printing in hex, but all my attempt to format the output as hex led to much longer strings than that one. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are Base64 encoding the digest, whereas you need to convert it to hex.  You can do this as @RedDeckWins recommends [using `map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729163/clojure-or-java-equivalent-to-rubys-hmac-hexdigest/31729268#31729268), but it would probably be more efficient to use a Java library.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208160/how-to-generate-an-hmac-in-java-equivalent-to-a-python-example/11102291#11102291) to a similar question uses `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex` to do the encoding.

Comment: Both answers work. Accepting this one because it's the one I ended up using. The funciton is `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex/encodeHexString`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, [excerpted from my github repo](https://github.com/dustinconrad/crypto-tutorial/blob/master/test/crypto_tutorial/lib/hmac_test.clj):

```
(ns crypto-tutorial.lib.hmac-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [crypto-tutorial.lib.util :refer :all]
            [crypto-tutorial.lib.hmac :as hmac]))

(defn sha-1-hmac-reference-impl [key bytes]
  (let [java-bytes (->java-bytes bytes)
        java-key (->java-bytes key)]
    (->>
      (doto (javax.crypto.Mac/getInstance "HmacSHA1")
        (.init (javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec. java-key "HmacSHA1")))
      (#(.doFinal % java-bytes))
      (map (partial format "%02x"))
      (apply str))))
```

Comment: Gah! One of my tries was that exact same code, but I used `%x` instead of `%02x`. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

For future reference, here is a complete ring middleware for validating GitHub webhook calls in Clojure based on the answers in this and the cited threads:

https://gist.github.com/ska2342/4567b02531ff611db6a1208ebd4316e6#file-gh-validation-clj

EDIT

The most important parts of the linked code are repeated here as (rightfully) requested in the comments.

```
;; (c) 2016 Stefan Kamphausen
;; Released under the Eclipse Public License 
(def ^:const ^:private signing-algorithm "HmacSHA1")

(defn- get-signing-key* [secret]
  (SecretKeySpec. (.getBytes secret) signing-algorithm))
(def ^:private get-signing-key (memoize get-signing-key*))

(defn- get-mac* [signing-key]
  (doto (Mac/getInstance signing-algorithm)
    (.init signing-key)))
(def ^:private get-mac (memoize get-mac*))

(defn hmac [^String s signature secret]
  (let [mac (get-mac (get-signing-key secret))]
    ;; MUST use .doFinal which resets mac so that it can be
    ;; reused!
    (str "sha1="
         (Hex/encodeHexString (.doFinal mac (.getBytes s))))))

(defn- validate-string [^String s signature secret]
  (let [calculated (hmac s signature secret)]
    (= signature calculated)))

;; Warn: Body-stream can only be slurped once. Possible
;; conflict with other ring middleware
(defn body-as-string [request]
  (let [body (:body request)]
    (if (string? body)
      body
      (slurp body))))

(defn- valid-github? [secrets request]
  (let [body (body-as-string request)
        signature (get-in request [:headers "x-hub-signature"])]
    (log/debug "Found signature" signature)
    (cond
      ;; only care about post
      (not (= :post (:request-method request)))
      "no-validation-not-a-post"

      ;; No secrets defined, no need to validate
      (not (seq secrets))
      "no-validation-no-secrets"

      ;; we have no signature but secrets are defined -> fail
      (and (not signature) (seq secrets))
      false

      ;; must validate this content
      :else
      (some (partial validate-string body signature) secrets))))

(def default-invalid-response
  {:status  400
   :headers {"Content-Type" "text/plain"}
   :body    "Invalid X-Hub-Signature in request."})

(defn wrap-github-validation
  {:arglists '([handler] [handler options])}
  [handler & [{:keys [secret secrets invalid-response]
               :or   {secret           nil
                      secrets          nil
                      invalid-response default-invalid-response}}]]
  (let [secs (if secret [secret] secrets)]
    (fn [request]
      (if-let [v (valid-github? secs request)]
        (do
          (log/debug "Request validation OK:" v)
          (handler (assoc request
                          :validation {:valid true
                                       :validation v}
                          ;; update body which must be an
                          ;; InputStream
                          :body (io/input-stream (.getBytes body)))))

        (do
          (log/warn "Request invalid! Returning" invalid-response)
invalid-response)))))
```